# inline combobox

Tags: extjs, combobox, extjs4

What is the best way to produce a in line combo box control in ExtJS4?

Example code:

```
        xtype:'container',
        items:[{
            xtype:"component",
            html:"this is some text that should appear before the combo: "
        },{
            xtype:'combo',
            queryMode: 'local',
            typeAhead: true,
            grow:true,
            store:["Alabama Alabama Alabama Alabama Alabama Alabama","Alaska","Arizona","Arkansas","California","Colorado","Connecticut","Delaware","Georgia"]
        },{
            xtype:"component",
            html:"this is some text that should appear after the combo."
        }]
```

Desired output:

```
this is some text that should appear before the combo:<combobox> this is some text that
should appear after the combo.
```

Answer (score 1):

add the following to the top level container:

```
layout: {
   type: 'hbox'
}
```

Comment: And you really want to have ExtJs component inside? Simple HTML element won't be enough?

Comment: Hm... I think you will be screwed then. :( I don't think there is easy way to achieve that

Comment: hbox dont let you add another row.. I want to make some form items inline but others should be under. how it can be done simply?

Comment: @kirlisakal: Post another question and describe what exactly you want to achieve and what have you tried so far.